# Custom control calling base method inside itself not working

Tags: c#, wpf

So I was trying to build a custom appender for log4net in a WPF project, using code like this:

```
public class RichTextBoxAppender : RichTextBox, IAppender
{
    void IAppender.Close()
    {
    }

    void IAppender.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage)));
            ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }
}
```

Nothing happened after I executed the program. For debugging purpose, I tried adding `Debug.WriteLine(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage)` to the lambda expression, which printed the logs correctly. I also tried calling `Document.Blocks.Add()` from MainWindow.xaml.cs, which also worked.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you configure the appender in log4net config?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes I did, or I won't get `Debug.WriteLine()` printed the logs.